# Woocommerce: How get a 10% discount used in the next order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to Calculate and subtract 10% from the total price of an item. But i need to let visitor to use it in the next order. and not for all visitor, Only for visitor that Always make purchases from the site or buy more than x times

I am using wordPess and Woocommerce plugin.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You could show the client a custom coupon after buying to let them get a discount if it's the first time. Just set the discount to 1 use in the wordpress settings. Also [here](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/search/wc-next-order-discount/) are some plugins to do just that.

Comment: you also have to add that you need to check that if this customer already bought something...

Comment: the plugins not available in URL

Comment: You can limit the coupon use to 1 per user in the coupon settings just like in [this image](http://imgur.com/9uKfnnP) Click on woocommerce settings -> coupons -> add new coupon and in the "limits" tab set the "use per user" to 1.

Comment: but i need for visitor that Always make purchases from the site or buy more than x times, and for all product.

Comment: @MerunasGrincalaitis are you understand my problem ?!